# SSMA Stalling WIndows 7

Tags: ms-access, windows-7, azure, tcp

I have a 500M access table 470K rows that I've tried repeatedly to upload to Azure using SSMA 32 bit windows 7.  It stalls at about row 140K.  I've reduced my batch size.  Was told to increase keepalive but don't see it in the registry key of WIndows 7.  How can something so basic be so complicated.  Help.

Answer (score 0):

How you first tried a local upsize to a local copy of sql server to see if some other problem exists here?

I would do a test run and send the data up to a local copy of SQL server. This would at least eliminate any issues of data or other reasons. If the upload runs without issue, then your internet connection (and perhaps even your local network connection) may be some issue in this failure.